# Celery and RabbitMQ eventually stopping due to memory exhaustion

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have Celery-based task queue with RabbitMQ as the broker. I am processing about 100 messages per day. I have no backend set up.

I start the task master like this:

```
broker = os.environ.get('AMQP_HOST', None)
app = Celery(broker=broker)
server = QueueServer((default_http_host, default_http_port), app)
```

... and I start the worker like this:

```
broker = os.environ.get('AMQP_HOST', None)
app = Celery('worker', broker=broker)
app.conf.update(
    CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1,
    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1,
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True,
)
```

The server runs correctly for quite some time, but after about two weeks it suddenly stops. I have tracked the stoppage down to RabbitMQ no longer receiving messages due to memory exhaustion:

```
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:252239992 allowed:249239961
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: =WARNING REPORT==== 25-Feb-2016::02:01:39 ===
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: memory resource limit alarm set on node rabbit@e654ac167b10.
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: **********************************************************
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: *** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
Feb 25 02:01:39 render-mq-1 docker/e654ac167b10[2189]: **********************************************************
```

The problem is I cannot figure out what needs to be configured differently to prevent this exhaustion. Obviously somewhere something is not being purged, but I don't understand what.

For instance, after about 8 days, rabbitmqctl status shows me this:

```
{memory,[{total,138588744},
      {connection_readers,1081984},
      {connection_writers,353792},
      {connection_channels,1103992},
      {connection_other,2249320},
      {queue_procs,428528},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,0},
      {other_proc,13555000},
      {mnesia,74832},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {msg_index,43243768},
      {other_ets,7874864},
      {binary,42401472},
      {code,16699615},
      {atom,654217},
      {other_system,8867360}]},
```

... when it was first started it was much lower:

```
{memory,[{total,51076896},
      {connection_readers,205816},
      {connection_writers,86624},
      {connection_channels,314512},
      {connection_other,371808},
      {queue_procs,318032},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,0},
      {other_proc,14315600},
      {mnesia,74832},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {msg_index,2115976},
      {other_ets,1057008},
      {binary,6284328},
      {code,16699615},
      {atom,654217},
      {other_system,8578528}]},
```

... even when all the queues are empty (except one job currently processing):

```
root@dba9f095a160:/# rabbitmqctl list_queues -q name memory messages messages_ready messages_unacknowledged
celery  61152   1   0   1
celery@render-worker-lg3pi.celery.pidbox    117632  0   0   0
celery@render-worker-lkec7.celery.pidbox    70448   0   0   0
celeryev.17c02213-ecb2-4419-8e5a-f5ff682ea4b4   76240   0   0   0
celeryev.5f59e936-44d7-4098-aa72-45555f846f83   27088   0   0   0
celeryev.d63dbc9e-c769-4a75-a533-a06bc4fe08d7   50184   0   0   0
```

I am at a loss to figure out how to find the reason for memory consumption. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems that your queue(s) (or exchanges) are going into flow state. Could you please check this - it' visible in the rabbitmq web UI

Comment: This particular server doesn't have the web UI installed or configured. Is there an easy way to find this information using the rabbitmqctl or other command-line tools? Also, from reading [Understanding flow control](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/), I'm not sure this is what's happening, as the description implies that the server can't keep up with incoming connections but requests have never yet come it an more than 3-4 per minute.

Comment: I don't know for command line... Yes, flow means that the publisher/s is/are too fast for the server., which could also be interpreted as the consumers are too slow on processing messages, but at the end it seems that only publishers cold cause this. https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue. I've never had more than about 20 items in the queue awaiting processing.

Comment: what is the total memory on the server? Is 2GB an appropriate limit for rabbitmq memory consumption? have you checked `dmesg` output to see if the kernel OOM killer has been invoked at any stage? have you run `htop` to see what the overall memory utilisation on the server is?

Comment: are you passing large amounts of data in your task messages?

Comment: Not at all... messages consist of a route ('render', fx, always a <50 char task name) and an object ID that is a long int.

Comment: I have not run those tools, still a relative beginner in monitoring long-running services and figuring those things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs say that you use 252239992 bytes, which is about 250Mb, which is not so high.
How many memory do you have on this machine and what is `vm_memory_high_watermark` value for rabbitmq? (you can check it by running `rabbitmqctl eval "vm_memory_monitor:get_vm_memory_high_watermark()."`)
Maybe you should just increase watermark.

Another option can be making all your queues `lazy` https://www.rabbitmq.com/lazy-queues.html

Comment: I am fairly sure this is not the issue. The problem is not that there are too many tasks in memory, it's that memory is gradually consumed over time even though the queue is empty the vast majority of the time.

Comment: The current watermark is the default, 40% of system RAM on a 600MB box. I could bump that threshold higher if that really is the right answer, my concern is that the continual growth in memory use will reach whatever mark I set and I will encounter the same problem again just at a different threshold. I want to find the root cause of the growth (if possible) and *then* set the threshold appropriately.

Comment: According to your memory usage, most memory is used by `message_index` and `binary`. This means that messages are not yet garbage collected, while being already deleted from queues.
If your messages are less then 4KB, you can set `queue_index_embed_msgs_below` to lower values to send all messages to message_store instead of message_index (to increase garbage collection rate) and enable lazy queues mentioned higher to store less messages in memory.
Anyway 256MB of memory is quite small amount for RabbitMQ to operate.

Comment: Ah, excellent, ok, that I can work with. Thanks, this is starting to make much more sense now.

Comment: What would be a 'typical' amount of memory for RabbitMQ to have available? Again, the overall amount of traffic is very low, so it's not really ever maintaining more than 10-20 active items in the queue at a time (usually the queue is empty).

Comment: Even though I have not fully explored and implemented this, in reading this part of the documentation I am much closer to understanding what's going on and I believe this is the bulk of the solution. Marking as the correct answer for now but will adjust in time if I find it's not complete.

Comment: Considering message index segment file entry count 16384 by default and 4KB messages being stored in index, worst case scenario will be approximately 64MB per queue. Also there can be GC delays on processes that's hibernated (rarely accessed queues) [you can read more here](http://blog.bugsense.com/post/74179424069/erlang-binary-garbage-collection-a-lovehate), so it's better to leave some memory above this numbers. 
If your machine is running RabbitMQ only you can increase watermark to utilise more memory, but mind that watermark is not absolute limit an RabbitMQ can consume more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be generating a huge volume of messages so the 2GB memory consumption seems strangely high. Nonetheless you could try getting rabbitmq to delete old messages - in your celery configuration set

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 'transient'
```

Comment: Should this be on the endpoint that is queueing tasks or on the endpoint that is consuming them, or both? It looks sender-specific, but just want to make sure.

Comment: In reading up on this at [Using Transient Queues](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html), it looks like this is about saving messages to disk instead of holding them in memory, but wouldn't they be deleted from disk anyway once they are completed? Also, it seems that saving to disk shouldn't consume larger and larger portions of memory over time?